# Angular / Ionic - How to save login information effectively

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

In my current implementation I save the user login & password in a local storage. At start, I read whether this info exists. If yes, I validate it against a server, if not, I open the login screen instead of the app.

However, it turns out that local storage is not the best solution as it can be deleted by the OS for seemingly random reasons (my iOS experience). This is annoying to the user as he has to re-login, maybe forgot his password already -> change password, ...

How do you solve this? SQLite ? File storage? Cookies ??
Is there a standard implementation I have not heard of?

Thanks
EL

Answer (score 1):

Local storage should work well. How are you saving it to local storage though? Some things may expire.

Check out this: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Also, I'd recommend not saving the password locally, you should authenticate with the server, get some auth token and save that.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please be more specific on the expiration of local storage? That's the main problem here. Yes, auth token is stored...

Answer (score 0):

I am using **angular-cache** plugin as it support to store object in local storage

https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache

This is my already template to login/logout users

```
angular.module('starter.services',[]).factory('Cache',function(CacheFactory){

  return {
    logIn : function(info){
      userCache = CacheFactory.get('userCache');

      if(userCache) CacheFactory.destroy('userCache');

      userCache = CacheFactory('userCache',{storageMode:"localStorage"});
      var put = userCache.put('user', info);
      return userCache;
    },
    checkLogIn : function(){
      var r = userInfo(CacheFactory);
      return r;
    },
    logOut : function() {
      var userCache = CacheFactory.get('userCache');

      if(userCache == undefined){
        userCache = CacheFactory('userCache',{storageMode:"localStorage"});
      }

      userCache.destroy();

      return userCache;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it persistent or did you experience random events where the local storage was gone because the OS erased it?

Comment: You have 3 choices in storage modes : 

`memory` : Cache will hold data in memory. Data is cleared when the page is refreshed.

`localStorage` : Cache will hold data in localStorage if available. Data is not cleared when the page is refreshed.

`sessionStorage` : Cache will hold data in sessionStorage if available. Data is not cleared when the page is refreshed.

Comment: In my app I set storageMode to `localStorage`. The data never goes even when the user update the application.

Comment: Hm, maybe I experienced it because I use the direct `window.localStorage`  access and not a package / library?

Comment: `window` is not defined in ionic app. You can use it only on browsers.

Comment: Android and iOS don't understand what window means. You should inject `$window` to your controller instead of `window`. But I don't know if `$window` supports localStorage or not

Comment: `var values = window.localStorage["Values"];` works for me on iOS and Android. I just copied the code...